# Redirecionar página se o usuário não interagir (click, touchstart, mousemove)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Preciso fazer um redirecionamento para uma "tela de descanso", se caso o usuário não interagir via clique/toque, arraste e movimento de mouse.

**O que conseguir fazer**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var meuTempo;

    meuTempo = setTimeout(openUrl, 5000); // redirecionamento

    function resetTimer(){
    clearTimeout(meuTempo); // dá um clear no tempo para dar reload
    }

    function openUrl(){
        window.location = "https://www.google.com.br/"; // reload
    }

    jQuery(document).bind("click mousemove touchstart", resetTimer); // reset de timer por interação

</script>
```

**O problema**

É necessário que sempre que o usuário não interagir, o contador seja setado novamente.

Ou seja, se o usuário interagir ele se mantém na página, se não, ele é redirecionado após X segundos para outra tela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use uma função para contar os segundos, e use utilize o bind abaixo para testar interações do Usuário:

`$(document).on("click keydown keyup mousemove")`

```js
var segundos = 0;
var timer = setInterval(testarInteracao, 1000); //1000 ms = 1 segundo

function testarInteracao(){
    segundos+= 1;
    
    if(segundos == 10){ //Limite máximo em Segundos
        window.location.href = "www.google.com.br";
    } 
    
    console.log(segundos)
}

$(document).on("click keydown keyup mousemove", function(){
    segundos = 0;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Caso precise de outros eventos**, coloque-os no mesmo bind do `$(document)` separados por espaço